# I can run the IOS emulator but project is not present

Tags: xcode, frontend, react-native-ios

Unfortunately, I've deleted my react native project with Xcode may it be the .xcworkspace file or .xcodeproj. file

So in order to get my project back with .xcodeproj, I had to rename my project eject and update react native. Having said that I am able to load the emulator but the project is still not present in the emulator. How do I reintegrate it back?

Here is the error that is seen on terminal:

```
      error Failed to build iOS project. 
        We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65.
     To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app,
 by opening Project.xcodeproj
```